# How to print jquery object/array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object

I get id and category name from mysql database.

When I am alerting a result, I get:

```
[{"id":"197","category":"Damskie"},"id":"198","category":"M\u0119skie"}]
```

(Is this object?)

1. How can I print a result like this:

   Damskie

   M\u0119skie
2. M\u0119ski - has bad encoding. It should be **Męskie**. How can I change this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
var arrofobject = [{"id":"197","category":"Damskie"},{"id":"198","category":"M\u0119skie"}];

$.each(arrofobject, function(index, val) {
    console.log(val.category);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

What you have from the server is a string like below:

```
var data = '[{"id":"197","category":"Damskie"},{"id":"198","category":"M\u0119skie"}]';
```

Then you can use `JSON.parse` function to change it to an object. Then you access the category like below:

```
var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(dataObj[0].category); //will return Damskie
console.log(dataObj[1].category); //will return Męskie
```

Comment: I use this example with jQuery.ajax() and it's working too. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your result is currently in string format, you need to parse it as json.

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
alert(obj[0].category);
```

Additionally, if you set the dataType of the ajax call you are making to `json`, you can skip the `$.parseJSON()` step.

Comment: OP never said it is an AJAX call :P

Comment: @Vega Very true, though if it isn't an ajax call, maybe it doesn't need to be json!

Comment: haha true.. was just kidding tho. Most likely, It should be an return from AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrofobject = [{"id":"197","category":"Damskie"},{"id":"198","category":"M\u0119skie"}];
var data = arrofobject.map(arrofobject => arrofobject);
console.log(data)
```

for more details please look at [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem and

```
var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(dataObj[0].category); //will return Damskie
console.log(dataObj[1].category); //will return Męskie
```

This solved my  problem. Thanks Selvakumar Arumugam