# Convert array of objects into HTML table with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I convert the following Javascript array of object

```
 [{"firstName":"John", "last Name":"Doe", "age":"46"},
 {"firstName":"James", "last Name":"Blanc", "age":"24"}]
```

Into HTML table like below

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>firstName</th>
      <th>last Name</th>
      <th>age</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</tD>
      <td>46</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>James</td>
      <td>Blanc</tD>
      <td>24</th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check here [Your Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231864/how-to-print-jquery-object-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print jquery object/array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231864/how-to-print-jquery-object-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```js
var rows = [{"firstName":"John", "last Name":"Doe", "age":"46"},
 {"firstName":"James", "last Name":"Blanc", "age":"24"}];
 var html = '<table>';
 html += '<tr>';
 for( var j in rows[0] ) {
  html += '<th>' + j + '</th>';
 }
 html += '</tr>';
 for( var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  html += '<tr>';
  for( var j in rows[i] ) {
    html += '<td>' + rows[i][j] + '</td>';
  }
  html += '</tr>';
 }
 html += '</table>';
 document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using `forEach` method , which accepts as parameter a `callback` provided function.

```js
var users=[{"firstName":"John", "last Name":"Doe", "age":"46"},
 {"firstName":"James", "last Name":"Blanc", "age":"24"}]
users.forEach(function(item){
  $('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+item.firstName+'</td><td>'+item["last Name"]+'</td><td>'+item.age+'</td></tr>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>firstName</th>
<th>last Name</th>
<th>age</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML put below code

```
<div id="myTable">

</div>
```

And in script put below code

```
var arrObj = [{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "age":"46"},
 {"firstName":"James", "lastName":"Blanc", "age":"24"}]
 var objLength = arrObj.length;
var myvar = '<table>'+
'<tr>'+
'<th>firstName</th>'+
'<th>last Name</th>'+
'<th>age</th>'+
'</tr>';

 for(var i = 0; i < objLength; i++){
myvar += '<tr>'+
'<td>'+arrObj[i].firstName+'</td>'+
'<td>'+arrObj[i].lastName+'</tD>'+
'<td>'+arrObj[i].age+'</th>'+
'</tr>'     
 }

 myvar += '</table>';

console.log(myvar);
 document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = myvar;
```

Hope this works